# React router dom not redirect correctly

Tags: javascript, react-router

That's my code, when i try to go in / or /home the components are rendered, but when i want to go in /login or /contacts it doesn't render, i don't know where is the problem, can someone help me?

```
 import React, { Component } from "react"
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import ContentInfo from './components/Card/Card';
import LoginCard from './components/LoginCard/LoginCard';
import ContactsCard from './components/ContactsCard/ContactsCard';
import RegisterCard from './components/RegisterCard/RegisterCard';
import {Root} from './components/Root';
import {HomeRoot} from './components/HomeRoot';
import Panel from './components/Panel/Panel';
import './components/particles.css';

class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path={"/"} exact>
                <Root>
                  <Route component={ContentInfo} />
                  <Route path={"/login"} exact component={LoginCard} />
                  <Route path={"/contacts"} component={ContactsCard} />
                  <Route path={"/register"} component={RegisterCard} />
                </Root>
              </Route>
              <Route path={"/home"}>
                <Switch>
                  <HomeRoot>
                    <Route component={Panel} />
                  </HomeRoot>
                </Switch>
              </Route>
            </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What exactly is Root? Are you simply trying to just switch on the paths /, /home, /contacts and /register?

Comment: yes, but when i try i only get blank page without the component

Comment: what is Root? Does LoginCard, ContactsCard and RegisterCard need to be a child of Root?

Comment: Root is a toolbar and login/contats/register cards are children of root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From our comment conversation if I understand correctly you are looking to do the following:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

.
.
.

const location = useLocation()

return (
<Router>
        <Switch>
           {location.pathname === '/home' ? <HomeRoot /> : <Root />}
           <Route exact path={"/"} component={ContentInfo} />
           <Route path={"/login"}  component={LoginCard} />
           <Route path={"/contacts"} component={ContactsCard} />
           <Route path={"/register"} component={RegisterCard} />
           <Route path={"/home"} component={Panel}>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: yes, with this solution all the root's children are rendered, but not for the HomeRoot (it is another toolbar)

Comment: One sec, let me see a solution for the /home route. I think I still misunderstand what you needed a little bit.

Comment: oke, so i need to divide the route in 2 parts, the first is for the Root toolbar with his children (login contacts register) and the second is for HomeRoot with panel and others

Comment: ah ok I see @Insan3

Comment: hey @Insan3 do you have to wrap the children in Root and HomeRoot. If not there could be a simpler way. I'll update my answer and let me know what you think.

Comment: The reason I ask is because one way of solving this by doing a condition on the location pathname. If they are at home then show HomeRoot if not then show Root. The tool bar would change conditionally. This might take some code refactoring but might be simpler.

Comment: This is assuming you are using react-router 5. If you are using react-router 4 its going to be a little different. If changing Root and HomeRoot is not possible then I will have to open up codesandbox and try to figure something else out.